# Unable to access saved code

Tags: python, jupyter, scraping

I am new to jupyter notebook and i can't find my saved .ipynb code after logging out of jupyter notebook accidentally.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: If you are using windows or mac, you can just search your computer for all .ipynb files in your hard drive. I'm sure you can also do this in most linux distributions too

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have made a file in your default document folder. A probable location for your notebook is where it starts if you have not changed the default path or maybe the location in which your files is located. Try to rerun your jupyter from your terminal or command prompt. It will open the contents of the folder you are looking for your notebook.

Answer (score 0):

The document will be at the place you started jupyter.

If you’re on Linux and don’t remember where you started jupyter, you can try

```
sudo updatedb 
locate ‘.ipynb’
```

It will search for ipynb files.
Otherwise try to search for ipynb files from the root folder of your OS.